# biblatex multi-bibliographies forced to use single page using "simple-resume-cv" template

Tags: biblatex

I am creating a CV using "[SIMPLE-RESUME-CV](https://github.com/zachscrivena/simple-resume-cv)", and I'm using biblatex to split out my works by type into individual sections.  I am getting the strangest error, though, in that it is almost as if all of the bibliographies are being wrapped into a single float that is then forced to print on a single page; and, given the total length of the bibligraphies, that means that some entries run off the bottom of the page.  That is, instead of treating each entry individually, and so splitting the content between pages accordingly, it is treating *all* the entries as a single monolithic block.

I am using XeLaTeX per the CV template instructions, and I am also using a sharelatex project.  I've made a copy of my CV using just the Simple CV template (so it won't have my personal information), but which uses the bibtex database [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/584dced2e473d1cf1e4c0b24).  Note that the "publications" should immediately follow after "Research Experience," but instead starts on the next page.  Moreover, observe that the entries count down to the fourth reference; the remaining three references are off the bottom of the page.  If you comment out the "Conferences" sub-section you get the desired behavior.  (With then notable exception that all my conference related publications are elided.)

I *suspect* that this is something very trivial, maybe some sort of option that I need to specify, or a variable value that needs to be changed.

---

**Update**: I have discovered the source of the problem.  The bulk of the CV is in an environment, body, that is defined as a longtable:

```
% Macro: body (rest of the document).
\newenvironment{body}
{\par\vspace{-1em}\par
\begin{longtable}{p{0.15\textwidth}p{0.80\textwidth}}}
{\par\end{longtable}\par}
```

This explains why each section is treated as a monolithic entity because they *are* one because each section is a cell in a longtable.

The kludge workaround is to comment out the \body tags in the LaTeX, but this results in poorly formatted pages.  I suggest academics do not use this template given that their bibliographies will likely trigger this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A minimal example is needed.

Comment: Again, I've duplicated the sharelatex project [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/584dced2e473d1cf1e4c0b24).  It has the advantage of having the same environmental setup as the original CV project.

However, if this is inadequate, I can cobble together another example.

Comment: An example you post here would be much more helpful and must more likely to elicit answers. Questions should not depend on the contents of external links: how much sense will this one make when that link disappears or the content changes? Moreover, people are much more likely to read and test a short example than they are to trawl through your entire code trying to find the problem.

Comment: Duly noted, though this is now moot as I've found and shared the ultimate source of the problem.  I've updated the title accordingly and posted an issue on the CV template's github.

Comment: In general, my advice is to not use 'templates' at all for CVs. Most of them seem to be badly designed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of "[simple-resume-cv](https://github.com/zachscrivena/simple-resume-cv)", and I believe I've fixed this problem in the latest release v3.0. Now the template uses a list for layout instead of the longtable package.
Do let me know if there are further issues.

Comment: Thank you for the update, Zach!  However, my CV edits were time critical, so I moved on to another template.  Hopefully your changes will be helpful, especially for academics that tend to have lengthy publication lists.